# Stop apt upgrade from replacing .desktop file

Tags: unity, apt, upgrade, 16.10, shortcuts

I have a HiDPI display so I often have to customize the `Exec` lines in `/usr/share/applications/*.desktop` files to add `--force-device-scale-factor=1.8`.

I'm finding that whenever Chrome or Spotify are upgraded by apt, this customization is lost.

Is there a persistent way I can do this that wont be lost on upgrade? Didn't apt used to ask whether you wanted to keep or replace files when you had modified them and they needed to be upgraded?

Is there a better place I should be putting these 'patches'?

Comment: I don't know about vanilla Ubuntu, but in Lubuntu one can put replacement desktop files in `/home/[username]/.local/share/applications/`. They override the ones in `/usr/share/applications` and aren't touched by updates.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: It works in plain vanilla Ubuntu too.

Comment: It only prompts about files that are marked as configuration files by the package maintainer, which is probably not the case for `.desktop` files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can put replacement desktop files in `/home/[username]/.local/share/applications/`. They override the ones in `/usr/share/applications/` and aren't touched by updates.

(Thanks to [AlexP](https://askubuntu.com/users/616021/alexp) for letting me know that this works in Ubuntu as well as Lubuntu)

Comment: A drawback is that possible changes of the package owned `.desktop` files will be overridden by the local ones.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson In this particular case, I don't see how that is a drawback.

Comment: @mchid: I mean that possible updates of .desktop via package upgrades won't be effective, since the local .desktop file is used instead.

Answer (score 1):

One thought is to use wrapper scripts. Example:

```
$ cat ~/bin/google-chrome
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/google-chrome --force-device-scale-factor=1.8 "$@"
```

If you make it executable with

```
chmod +x ~/bin/google-chrome
```

it might do what you are after.